# How to retrieve file path from an open IOStream in Julia

Tags: file, io, julia

I open some file:

```
myfilepath = "/home/colin/somefile.csv"
fid = open(myfilepath, "r")
```

I would like to retrieve the file path from `fid`. I can use:

```
fid.name
```

and this will return something like:

```
"<file /home/colin/somefile.csv>
```

However, as near as I can tell, this isn't documented, so I've got no guarantee this solution is future-proof.

So, my question is, is there a safe method to retrieve the file-path of an open `IOStream` from the `IOStream` itself?

Comment: I tried ``read(`readlink /proc/self/fd/$(fd(fp))`, String)``, but appearently the command's process does not inherit file descriptors...

Comment: In most programming languages `IOStream` is an abstract concept that does not care where the bytes are coming from. This can be memory, network sockets. disks etc. Hence, unless a concept such as `FileIOStream` exists, I would not expect from an `IOStream` to care and know where actually the data is coming from.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Interesting. I hadn't really thought about it like that but it does make sense. I suppose I could do something like `struct FileIOStream ; filepath::String, io::IOStream ; end`, and write some simple functionality around it. On the other hand, that's probably more work than just passing a tuple of the `IOStream` and the filepath around the functions in my code :-)

Comment: @phipsgabler `readlink("/proc/self/fd/$(RawFD(fd(fp)))")` might work, but only on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no such function exists in base Julia. This can be determined by looking at the complete list of functions defined for the type `IOStream`:

```
julia> methodswith(IOStream)
[1] crc32c(io::IOStream) in CRC32c at /Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/CRC32c/src/CRC32c.jl:50
[2] crc32c(io::IOStream, crc::UInt32) in CRC32c at /Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/CRC32c/src/CRC32c.jl:50
[3] bytesavailable(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:377
[4] close(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:61
[5] eof(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:232
[6] fd(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:55
[7] filesize(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:222
[8] flush(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:66
[9] isopen(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:59
[10] isreadable(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:75
[11] iswritable(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:73
[12] peek(s::IOStream, ::Type{UInt8}) in Base at iostream.jl:568
[13] position(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:216
[14] read(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:516
[15] read(s::IOStream, ::Type{UInt8}) in Base at iostream.jl:396
[16] read(s::IOStream, T::Union{Type{Int16}, Type{Int32}, Type{Int64}, Type{UInt16}, Type{UInt32}, Type{UInt64}}) in Base at iostream.jl:405
[17] read(s::IOStream, ::Type{Float16}) in Base at iostream.jl:417
[18] read(s::IOStream, ::Type{Float32}) in Base at iostream.jl:418
[19] read(s::IOStream, ::Type{Float64}) in Base at iostream.jl:419
[20] read(s::IOStream, nb::Integer; all) in Base at iostream.jl:557
[21] readavailable(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:379
[22] readbytes!(s::IOStream, b::Union{SubArray{UInt8, var"#s828", var"#s827", I, true} where {var"#s828", var"#s827"<:(Array{UInt8, N} where N), I<:Union{Tuple{Vararg{Real, N} where N}, Tuple{AbstractUnitRange, Vararg{Any, N} where N}}}, Array{UInt8, N} where N}) in Base at iostream.jl:509
[23] readbytes!(s::IOStream, b::Union{SubArray{UInt8, var"#s826", var"#s825", I, true} where {var"#s826", var"#s825"<:(Array{UInt8, N} where N), I<:Union{Tuple{Vararg{Real, N} where N}, Tuple{AbstractUnitRange, Vararg{Any, N} where N}}}, Array{UInt8, N} where N}, nb; all) in Base at iostream.jl:509
[24] readline(s::IOStream; keep) in Base at iostream.jl:444
[25] readuntil(s::IOStream, delim::UInt8; keep) in Base at iostream.jl:435
[26] redirect_stderr(handle::Union{IOStream, Base.LibuvStream}) in Base at stream.jl:1148
[27] redirect_stdin(handle::Union{IOStream, Base.LibuvStream}) in Base at stream.jl:1148
[28] redirect_stdout(handle::Union{IOStream, Base.LibuvStream}) in Base at stream.jl:1148
[29] seek(s::IOStream, n::Integer) in Base at iostream.jl:127
[30] seekend(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:161
[31] show(io::IO, s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:35
[32] skip(s::IOStream, delta::Integer) in Base at iostream.jl:184
[33] stat(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:57
[34] take!(s::IOStream) in Base at iostream.jl:432
[35] truncate(s::IOStream, n::Integer) in Base at iostream.jl:106
[36] unsafe_read(s::IOStream, p::Ptr{UInt8}, nb::UInt64) in Base at iostream.jl:422
[37] unsafe_write(s::IOStream, p::Ptr{UInt8}, nb::UInt64) in Base at iostream.jl:371
[38] write(s::IOStream, b::UInt8) in Base at iostream.jl:366
```

The closest of any of these to what you are looking for is `stat`, which can give you the inode of the underlying file, but not the file path per se.

```
help?> stat
search: stat lstat @static startswith stacktrace StackTraces @fastmath ignorestatus InvalidStateException abstract AbstractSet AbstractChar AbstractDict abstract type AbstractFloat AbstractArray AbstractRange AbstractMatch

  stat(file)

  Returns a structure whose fields contain information about the file. The fields of the structure are:

  Name    Description
  ––––––– ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  size    The size (in bytes) of the file
  device  ID of the device that contains the file
  inode   The inode number of the file
  mode    The protection mode of the file
  nlink   The number of hard links to the file
  uid     The user id of the owner of the file
  gid     The group id of the file owner
  rdev    If this file refers to a device, the ID of the device it refers to
  blksize The file-system preferred block size for the file
  blocks  The number of such blocks allocated
  mtime   Unix timestamp of when the file was last modified
  ctime   Unix timestamp of when the file was created
```